# Running script after window.open

Tags: javascript

```
window.open('https://starve.io/')

setTimeout(() => {


let c = prompt ("What is the password?")

let password = ['Ax', 'Buax','Oyl'];

function detectpassword(){
    if (c == password) {
        alert ('Thats the correct password');
    } else {
        alert ('Sorry thats wrong');
        window.close()
    }
}

detectpassword(); 
}, 10000);
```

Hello , what I'm trying to do that open that new window then execute the script on it but It just opens  the new window and executes the script on the previous page not the one I just opened.

Comment: there is a reason why you cannot execute a script on another page you are redirecting to, if the new page is under your control you should have no issue making it do whatever you wish.. but if not, then it's not for you to decide ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you don't own the target site `starve.io`. You will not be able to execute an arbitrary script there. This is a security measure. If this was not the case, anyone could embed `starve.io` full-screen and read any data from it.

To execute an arbitrary script on anothre page you will need to create browser extension. Then you can use cross-tab communication to forward the password to your application.

Comment: Thanks, I dont own the website, I just added random site to test, looks like I need to have access to it.

Comment: If you own the website, i.E. it's on the same domain, you can access the content. you can then call the 'eval' function othe inner window.